# Ciphering method where N out of M keys are required for decryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Which ciphering method allows to decrypt data with *N* out of *M* keys?

Example: There are 5 persons, each of them gets an individual key. They should be able to decrypt encrypted data, but at least 3 of them (any combination) should be required to decrypt it.

Comment: are you looking for DSA?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I'm not sure if this is possible with DSA

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan DSA is not an encryption scheme, it can only be used for creating and verifying signatures.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger Are you sure that Digital Signature Algorithm is used for creating signatures? Joking aside, I think DHIES is probably the closest you get. But that's probably not interesting for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technical name for what you want is a threshold scheme. There are several different varieties; Google will point you to them. If you are interested, I have an implementation of Adi Shamir's threshold system at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/06/17/adi-shamirs-threshold-scheme/).

Comment: I didn't know how they are called, but now I have something to look for. Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, other terms you will also see are "secret sharing schemes", "(m,n) secret sharing schemes" or "(m,n) threshold schemes". A threshold scheme is one type of secret sharing scheme.